# onMapReady not calling even though the map display without any error

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to display a simple map using Google map API v2 in an Android application. I'm following the [Map API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map) instructions. But I think the `onMapReady` is not calling for some reason. I'm using `google-play-services_lib` version `6587000`. My phone has `google-play-services_lib` verion `6587038`, I believe.

Google map is working with initial controls. Can someone help me to correct this error?

```
public class MapDisplay extends FragmentActivity
implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Location mCurrentLocation;
private MarkerOptions mMarkerOptions ;
    private MapFragment mMapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.location_map);

    /** not needed
            mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getFragmentManag

er().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map, mMapFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();*/

    /**corrected code*/
            MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    toast("Map ready");
    Log.d("--***** MAP  ","::Map ready");

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Sydney")
            .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
            .position(sydney));


    }

 private void toast(String text){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
     }

   }
```

> location_map.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

AFAIK, `onMapReady()` is triggered by a call to `getMapAsync()` on your `MapFragment`, and I do not see where you are calling that.

Comment: @SAN: "getMapAsync() throw and error" -- then perhaps you should consider asking a Stack Overflow question to get assistance with whatever problem you had there. "so I had to use" -- so? AFAIK, you still need to call `getMapAsync()`. Moreover, now you have *two* `MapFragment` instances. Here is a sample project that demonstrates the use of `getMapAsync()` with a static `MapFragment`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/NooYawk

Comment: It will be helpful for someOne else if in xml your <fragment name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportFragment" then use SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment

Answer (score 13):

To call `OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)`, append the following to your `onCreate(...)` method :

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) 
    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

then, add:

```
// This calls OnMapReady(..). (Asynchronously)
mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapDisplay.this);
```

Answer (score -2):

Add:

```
mMap = map
```

above `onMapReady`